# How do I set multiple cookies in hooks.js?

Tags: sveltekit

I keep failing to set multiple cookies in following code:

```js
//  src/hooks.js

import cookie from 'cookie';

export const handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    console.log('handle');
    const cookies = cookie.parse(event.request.headers.get('cookie') || '');
    event.locals.sessionId = cookies.sessionId || null;
    const response = await resolve(event);
    if (event.locals.sessionId) {
        response.headers.set(
            'set-cookie',
            cookie.serialize('sessionId', event.locals.sessionId, {
                path: '/',
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
                maxAge: 604800
            })
        );
    }
    return response;
};
```

Any working examples out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `response.headers.append('set-cookie', /* cookie */)` instead of `.set(...)`

According to the [Fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-headers%E2%91%A0), `append` will append a header while `set` will replace the value of the header with the new value.